# time-consume of spring bean loading

Tags: spring

I'm trying to reduce the time my Junit-test consumes. Because there are hundreds of beans in my XML files relating to all the testing while I use only two or three of them.

Firstly, I used the *immediate-instantiate*, all the beans were loaded at the very beginning.The time it consumed are as below:

37593、33672、32187、32141、32641(milliseconds)

When I changed the instantiate way to *lazy-init*, The time it consumed are as below:

18484、3784、3562、2859  (milliseconds)

Can anybody tell me why is there a sharp reduction between the first and the second time in the lazy-init way?

Comment: Did you read the docs on what "lazy-init" does? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init

Comment: I mean when I used lazy-init for the first time, it cost 18484ms to load the xml, but the second time I used lazy-init, it cost only 3784ms. I know what lazy-init means.Maybe I didn't say my problem clearly, I'm terribly for that.

Comment: I think the overhead in the first case is not caused by spring but other initiations required by your testing environment. What happens when you remove the lazy-init after the fourth run with the lazy-init?

Comment: When a unit-test teminated, the javaw.exe was killed too. so everytime I run the unit test, the resources shall be loaded anew.What's more, when I ran the test a long time later, it is like the first case and cost more than 18 seconds. So is it something about OS(Windows XP)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy-init means, that only the beans that are needed at startup are instanciated. All other bean instanciations will be delayed until needed.

To speed your tests up even more, you could simply build a seperate XML config especially for your unit tests, that only contains the beans you need. The only drawback is the extra amount of care you have to take, so that the files stay synchronized.

Comment: Thanks!But I still wonder why I used the lazy-init way the first used 18484 milliseconds, but the second time cost only 3784 milliseconds